# VS 2017 Document-level add-in build fails with com visible components

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto, visual-studio-2017

I have VS 2013 installed and I added 2017 RC.
I made a document-level modified excel solution with some customisation in C# and this works fine.
Then I added some VBA code in the spreadsheet and added a com-visible class following [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb386306%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (which fails if I try to open it in chrome but works ok in edge).

In ThisWorkbook.cs I have the following code...

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WeekendingTabsNET40
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IWeekending
    {
        string DisplayTaggedSheets ();
        string DisplayDates ();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class QueryWeekending : IWeekending
    {
        private readonly WeekEnding.WeekEnding _we;
        public QueryWeekending ()
        {
            _we = Globals.ThisWorkbook?.WeekEnding;
        }
        string IWeekending.DisplayTaggedSheets ()
        {
            return _we.DisplayTaggedSheets();
        }
        string IWeekending.DisplayDates ()
        {
            return _we.DisplayDates();
        }
    }

    public partial class ThisWorkbook
    {
        public WeekEnding.WeekEnding WeekEnding;

        private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            WeekEnding = new WeekEnding.WeekEnding(this, Globals.Factory);
        }

        private void ThisWorkbook_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override object GetAutomationObject ()
        {
            return new QueryWeekending();
        }

        #region VSTO Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisWorkbook_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisWorkbook_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

After I set `ReferenceAssemblyFromVbaProject` to true and build the project, I get the following error...

> Error MSB3217: Cannot register assembly "obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (1, 1)

[image]

This with an elevated instance of VS 2017 RC.
Can anybody advise what is the problem?

---

### Build output

```
Rebuild All started ...
  Build started 21/02/2017 2:26:37 AM.
       1>Project "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40.sln" on node 1 (WeekendingTabsNET40:Rebuild target(s)).
       1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
           Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
       1>Project "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40.csproj" (2) on node 1 (Rebuild target(s)).
       2>Project "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40.csproj" (2) is building "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekEndingTabs\WeekEnding\WeekEnding.csproj" (3:3) on node 1 (default targets).
       3>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
         Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
         CoreCompile:
           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /link:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" /link:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll" /link:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.v4.0.Framework.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\WeekEnding.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs WeekEnding.cs "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
           Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
         _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
           Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll" to "bin\Debug\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll".
           Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.dll" to "bin\Debug\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.dll".
           Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities.dll" to "bin\Debug\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities.dll".
           Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.v4.0.Framework.dll" to "bin\Debug\Microsoft.Office.Tools.v4.0.Framework.dll".
           Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll" to "bin\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll".
         CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
           Copying file from "obj\Debug\WeekEnding.dll" to "bin\Debug\WeekEnding.dll".
           WeekEnding -> C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekEndingTabs\WeekEnding\bin\Debug\WeekEnding.dll
           Copying file from "obj\Debug\WeekEnding.pdb" to "bin\Debug\WeekEnding.pdb".
       3>Done Building Project "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekEndingTabs\WeekEnding\WeekEnding.csproj" (default targets).
       2>CoreResGen:
           "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\resgen.exe" /useSourcePath /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /r:"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekendingTabsNET40\packages\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.15.0.4795.1000\lib\net20\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /r:"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekEndingTabs\WeekEnding\bin\Debug\WeekEnding.dll" /compile Properties\Resources.resx,obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.Properties.Resources.resources Sheet1.resx,obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.Sheet1.resources ThisWorkbook.resx,obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.QueryWeekending.resources
           Processing resource file "Properties\Resources.resx" into "obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.Properties.Resources.resources".
           Processing resource file "Sheet1.resx" into "obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.Sheet1.resources".
           Processing resource file "ThisWorkbook.resx" into "obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.QueryWeekending.resources".
         GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
         Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
         CoreCompile:
           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /warn:4 /define:VSTO40;DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /link:"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekendingTabsNET40\packages\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.15.0.4795.1000\lib\net20\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /reference:"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekEndingTabs\WeekEnding\bin\Debug\WeekEnding.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /resource:obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.Properties.Resources.resources /resource:obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.Sheet1.resources /resource:obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.QueryWeekending.resources /target:library /utf8output Chart1.cs Chart1.Designer.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Sheet1.cs Sheet1.Designer.cs Sheet10.cs Sheet10.Designer.cs Sheet11.cs Sheet11.Designer.cs Sheet2.cs Sheet2.Designer.cs Sheet3.cs Sheet3.Designer.cs Sheet4.cs Sheet4.Designer.cs Sheet5.cs Sheet5.Designer.cs Sheet6.cs Sheet6.Designer.cs Sheet7.cs Sheet7.Designer.cs Sheet8.cs Sheet8.Designer.cs Sheet9.cs Sheet9.Designer.cs ThisWorkbook.cs ThisWorkbook.Designer.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
           Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(628,9): error MSB3217: Cannot register assembly "obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
       2>Done Building Project "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.
       1>Done Building Project "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40.sln" (WeekendingTabsNET40:Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.

  Build FAILED.

  Time Elapsed 00:00:01.59
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

### Errors

> Error MSB3217 Cannot register assembly
>   "obj\Debug\WeekendingTabsNET40.dll". Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>     C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40\WeekendingTabsNET40.csproj  C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets 628

### Update

I was able to clear all of the duplicates in the downloads cache using gacutil but it made no difference.

### It seems like the problem is that I don't have Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll in the GAC.

I can see this file here...

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   \Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll

But it's not in the GAC (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL)

So... I added it but of course its ver 12.0.0.0 that I have so I guess I need to find a way to download the 15.0.0.0 version.

Comment: Looks like the debug build doesn't exist, therefore cannot be registered for COM interop. The *build* output should have more useful information. Would you happen to have an Excel instance opened? Verify in Task Manager that no EXCEL.EXE process is running.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, no excel processes running and I can't see any build events in the output window... Oh, OK, switched from re-sharper to VS build and posted the output...

Comment: VS being unable to delete the type library is definitely pointing to the type library being already in use, which points to an EXCEL.EXE process still running. Did you check the "Processes" tab or just the "Applications" in task manager?

Comment: @Mat'sMug, after I rushed to post the output I noticed that it was failing to delete (I hadn't seen that before) then I checked and found an orphan VS compiler process running. Terminated that re-built, please see updated question...

Comment: You are using a beta version of VS2017.  Could be that the install did not go well, but these are exactly the kind of problems you run into with betas.  I vaguely remember reading a readme where they mentioned improving VSTO, so high odds that it simply isn't done yet.   Just wait another two weeks until the RTM version ships.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, I've been confusing myself: VS is trying to load ver 15.0.0.0 and the version on my install is 12.0.0.0, so, I guess the install is not fully updated.  I was thinking that maybe it was because I jumped from 2013 to 2017 RC.

Comment: @HansPassant, FYI, I eventually figured it out. Your comment helped to clear my thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this.
My main problem was understanding the configuration diaspora around VS.  The DLL I needed was actually in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll
```

because I have VS 2017 RC installed, this is where the ver 15 DLLs are and the one that MSBuild is expecting to find.
So, finally, I just added that version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll to the GAC by opening the VS Command Prompt (as admin) and running

```
gacutil /i C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll
```

So, apart from understanding the configuration friction (which is not really described properly in the msdn docs rubic's cube), I just needed to realise that the correct version of VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll needed to be registered in the GAC.
As mentioned by @HansPassant, the VS 2017 RC install failed to take care of this.

Answer (score -1):

Besides that, I did before without solving the problem.
I tried again use gacutil to register `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll".`
Then using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 as Administrator I did the correct registration of `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll"`, and after that no more problems to build the "
Walkthrough: Calling Code from VBA in Visual C# Project works fine until the step Exposing the Method to VBA code
". In my computer, I found `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll"` in the patch

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\`