# What is Download subfolder in GAC

Tags: .net, visual-studio, gac

While trying to get some com interop to work with excel I seem to have created a lot of duplicate native image files in the gac (which I think I need to delete).  But they are in a subfolder as shown in the following image...

[image]

There are many duplicates with the same codeBase so I guess visual studio is doing a crap job of cleaning up after itself.

When I use regservr32 to uninstall shfusion I can't see these as dll's.  Is this because they are linked to the "CodeBase" rather than stored in the GAC as dll's?

What is the Download subfolder all about?

What is the best way to get rid of these?  Just repeatedly running regasm?

---

So nobody knows anything about this?

Anyway, I figured out how to clear the downloads cache using

```
C:\Users\Admin\Source>gacutil /cdl
```

from Developer command Prompt for VS 20XX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the HTTP Download Cache.  Getting pretty obscure, just about nobody still writes code that still uses it.  Made some sense in the early days of .NET when everybody still used IE6 and sys-admins didn't yet started blocking ActiveX content.

Technical info on that cache is hard to come by.  Still mentioned in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2005/02/20/download-cache/) but the linked blog post with the goodies died when gotdotnet.com was discontinued.  No backup in the wayback machine either.

Pretty hard to explain why you see your assembly back when you tested it in Excel.  Afaik it is only used for assemblies that get loaded into Internet Explorer.  The folder is not real, just an illusion from the shell extension implemented by shfusion.dll that hides the .NET 2.0 GAC content.  Actual storage location is C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3

It works just like the normal web browser cache.  I presume kept separate because of the extra detail of AssemblyVersion and the PublicKeyToken.  Surely you see it back more than once because of different timestamps of your assembly, perhaps created when you were testing your library.  Clean-up is automatic, like it is for the browser cache, Fusion starts deleting files when total storage size exceeds 50MB.  Have a look-see by navigating to the folder from the command prompt.  Type dir /s to see the dates on the files and their total size.  Well, a bit too late since you killed it with gacutil /cdl.  Otherwise best to treat it the same way you do the browser cache, no compelling need to micro-manage it.

Comment: OK, yes, I can see it there. As you suggest, VS is creating new versions every time I re-build and run the app.  It's a doc-level VSTO addin, so I think its a VSTO thing.  Thanks for explaining: one less thing to blame for my [VBA/VSTO interop problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42347958/2670182)